# Creating #define PTM_RATIO for universal app

Tags: box2d, cocos2d-x

I have a cocos2d-x/box2d project I want the #define of the PTM_RATIO to be different for ipod and ipad deployment. How do I go about setting up this #define in c++?

So far after searching the internet I've tried putting this code in an objective-c file

```
#ifdef UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM
#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#else
#define IS_IPAD false
#endif
#define PTM_RATIO (IS_IPAD ? 32 : 16)
```

But IS_IPAD always defines false when testing on an ipad, and removing the #ifdef says UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() is undeclared.

Help getting this to work would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#define PTM_RATIO ((UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) ? 32.0 :16.0)
```

You can try also to define some macros for each device and use them.

e.g.

```
#define IS_IPAD UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad
#define IS_IPHONE UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone
#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( IS_IPHONE && IS_HEIGHT_GTE_568 )
// ...
#define PTM_RATIO ( IS_IPHONE_5 && I_IPAD ) ? yesvalue : novalue
```

You can play with that